# Scrapy > Crawl loop while login to a forum with hidden token authentication

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm learning how to use Scrapy to retrieve a forum page and stock it onto my server. The forum uses a hidden token based authentication.

As I'm a beginner in Python coding I built a crawler from this example: https://python.gotrained.com/scrapy-formrequest-logging-in/ and I tested it on the http://quotes.toscrape.com/ website.

Here is my scrapy script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class QuotesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ('http://quotes.toscrape.com/login',)

    next_url = ('http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/love/',)

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'csrf_token': token,
                                                   'username': 'pouet',
                                                   'password': 'pouet'},
                                         callback=self.scrape_pages, errback=self.errback)

    def scrape_pages(self, response):
        for url in self.next_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url)
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

    def errback(self, failure):
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))
```

I want to load the http://quotes.toscrape.com/login page, fill out the login form, access to the secured page (which is for this example http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/love/) and download the source code into a HTLM file.

But what I get is a loop on the parse function with the form filling. In the log it says:
***No form element found in <200 [http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/love/>](http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/love/%3E)***

How to avoid this loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scrapy after login successfully, its redirect to `http://quotes.toscrape.com/`. You need to redirect  `'http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/love/'`
So here is an example that help you.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest


class QuotesSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'quotes'
    login_page = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/love/']

    def init_request(self):
        return scrapy.Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        print()
        print(response.url)
        print()
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'csrf_token': token,
                                                   'username': 'pouet',
                                                   'password': 'pouet'},
                                         callback=self.login_page_response)

    def login_page_response(self, response):
        print('login page ', response.url)
        if "tag/love/" in response.body.decode('utf-8'):
            print()
            print('found it')

            return self.initialized()


    def parse(self, response):
        print( response.url, response.url.split('/'))
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: If its help you, please accept and up vote my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much @Samsul-Islam, your solution works very well in my example above with the Quotes website. However, it doesn't work on the forum I want to crawl because there is an intermediate logging page which is generated after filling the form. Scrapy loads this intermediate page, save it and stop here before going to the start_urls. Do you know how to handle this? Thanks

Comment: I voted up but as I have a reputation score of only 1 for the moment the up vote will not be shown.

Comment: I manage to run my crawler! I deleted the line `if "tag/love/" in response.body.decode('utf-8'):` and it works. Thanks again